Why did Peter not preach that Jesus was the Son of God in Acts 2?
This question is related to Peter's sermon in Acts 2:14-36.
I am assuming that the following assumptions/claims are correct:

Luke transcribed from a witness (with divine inspiration) or wrote (by divine revelation) the entirety of Peters' sermon, until his audience (Jews of Judea, Jews of the Dispersion, and Proselytes), standing outside the upper room, asked him how to proceed ("what should we do...")
Peter knew that Jesus was the Son of God, to mean God in flesh but he "just" preached Jesus to be Lord and Christ
Saul (Paul) preached Jesus both Son of God, and being the Christ right after his conversion (Acts 9:19-22).
Jesus being the Christ (or the Messiah [the Anointed One]) does NOT imply Jesus being God incarnated/in flesh
Jesus Being the Son of God DOES imply Jesus being God incarnated/in flesh

Question #1
Does Jesus being the Lord imply Jesus being God incarnated/in flesh? If not, see the following questions.
Question #2
How have those 3,000 Jews been baptized without believing Jesus being the Son of God, God in flesh?
Question #3
Is it theologically acceptable to be converted to Christianity without coming to this understanding (that Jesus is God the Son) until perhaps later in life?
Question #4
After searching in the NT from Acts to Revelation, there seems to be a huge emphasis on Jesus being the Christ (anointed one) vs being the Son of God as if the former was more important than the latter:

Christ: 468 occurrences (NASB 2020)
Son of God: 17 occurrences (NASB 2020)

Why is that?

Why is this question an issue with you? Look at Matthew 16:13-20. Jesus ask His disciples, Who do people say that the Son of Man is? At vs16 the Apostle Peter said, "Thou are the Christ, the Son of the living God." At vs17 Jesus said, "Blessed are you Simon Barjona, because flesh and blood did not reveal this to you, but My Father who is in heaven." My point is Peter acknowledge Jesus as the Son of God about 20 years before the book of Acts was written. The gospel of Matthew is a "didactic" book/teaching book. Acts is a  narrative primarily describes the events of the early church

@Mr. Bond "Why is this question an issue with you?" I believe Question #2 and Question #3 are the OPs primary concerns.

@Austin My curiosity was this statement, "Peter knew that Jesus was the Son of God, to mean God in flesh but he "just" preached Jesus to be Lord and Christ" And this statement, "Saul (Paul) preached Jesus both Son of God, and being the Christ right after his conversion (Acts 9:19-22)." Explain his point? Then explain his implication here: Jesus being the Christ (or the Messiah [the Anointed One]) does NOT imply Jesus being God incarnated/in flesh. And here: Jesus Being the Son of God DOES imply Jesus being God incarnated/in flesh.  How can one know the implication on less you study the Bible?

@Mr.Bond (Part 1/2) I have no issue with Peter (and the twelve) believing that Jesus was God incarnated. I already stated this in claim #2. Peter preached the Gospel to the crowd. The crowd asked how to respond (and to be saved). Peter told them how to be saved: repent and be baptized. Nowhere in his sermon he said anything about Jesus' deity until he told them what to do to be saved. That means, everything the crowd needed to know to be saved has already been explicitly taught by Peter until they decide to be baptized.

@Mr.Bond (Part 2/2) Now, if it is required to believe that Jesus is God incarnated before becoming a Christian, then the 3,000 believed that Jesus was God in flesh before being saved. How did they understand that? From Peter's sermon? When he said that "God made Jesus Lord and Christ"? Did the word 'Lord' necessarily carry the meaning of deity? If so, what does it mean God made Jesus divine? If not, then God made Jesus Lord to just mean the Master? Then the question remains open.

Not to mention that the crowd was made up mostly of Jews from the diaspora. They might not have been as acquainted with Jesus' ministry and claims of deity as the Jews from Judea.

The title "Son of God" has different meanings for Jews and Christian today. Christians associate it with the divinity of Jesus, while early Jews understood it as synonymous with the Messiah, who was primarily seen as a human figure.
Peter experienced a breakthrough in revelation in Matthew 16:16, proclaiming "Jesus as the Messiah, the Son of the living God." This revelation earned praise from Jesus, who said in Matthew 16:17, "This is not revealed to you by flesh and blood, but by my Father in heaven." It is unclear whether Peter recognized the full divinity of Jesus at this moment. However, in Matthew 16:21-23, Jesus rebuked Peter for focusing on human concerns, indicating that Peter's revelation might have been incomplete.
According to Exodus 4:22-23, Israel as a nation is referred to as "Son of God". For Jews, the title "Messiah" and "Lord" hold significant meaning. The Messiah represents the Savior that God promises to Israel from the line of David, who will restore their nation. In Peter's speech in Acts 2:14-36, where the audience were all Jews, it was appropriate for Peter to emphasize Jesus as the Messiah and the Lord. These titles carried a more specific understanding for the Jews than the term "Son of God".
Christianity is considered a faith based on progressive revelation. The doctrine of the Trinity is crucial in establishing the divinity of Jesus within Christian theology. The Gospel of John, which affirms Jesus divinity, was written decades after Peter's speech in Acts 2. Therefore it is unclear if Peter recognized Jesus' divinity at that time. However, even if Peter did know,  it might not have been the right time to introduce such a radical concept to contemporary Jews. Even today, not all Christians accept the concept of the Trinity.

The Gospel of John, which affirms Jesus divinity. Where does it do that?

There are multiple questions listed here, which is not usually encouraged on this site. However they all seem to flow from the basic question in the title:

Why did Peter not preach that Jesus was the Son of God in Acts 2?

My first response is that this feels like asking, Why did Peter not preach the sermon the way I would have? In reality, Peter preached what he preached, and it is the responsibility of those who follow to interpret his words, not to rewrite them.
More specifically, I would note the following details:

The fact that Peter used a given term to describe Jesus doesn't mean that Peter has rejected other terms. Maybe he was using terms that he felt were most meaningful to his audience.

The fact that the Jewish audience responded to Peter's call to repent and be baptised, is good evidence that God honoured the content of Peter's sermon.

It's clear from Acts 2:40 ("With many other words...") that this is not a transcription but a summary of what Peter said.

It's also clear from a survey of the New Testament records that a wide range of labels was used by both Jesus himself and his disciples. They all have value, and they all contribute to our overall understanding of who Jesus was.



Acts 2:40 ("With many other words...") took place after Peter told the crowd what to do to be saved. This means there is nothing more to be added by Peter or anyone else to be saved. Peter's "saving" speech is complete at Acts 2:38 and the crowd now just needs to act on it: repent and be baptized. Until then, no divinity of Jesus has been preached to the best of my knowledge.

Assumption:


Peter knew that Jesus was the Son of God, to mean God in flesh but he "just" preached Jesus to be Lord and Christ


Don't stop at verse 36:

40 And with many other words did he testify and exhort, saying, Save yourselves from this untoward generation.
41 Then they that gladly received his word were baptized: and the same day there were added unto them about three thousand souls.

There is no reason to conclude that those "many other words" didn't give the assumed to be missing details.

Acts 2:40 ("With many other words...") took place after Peter told the crowd what to do to be saved. This means there is nothing more to be added by Peter or anyone else to be saved. Peter's "saving" speech is complete at Acts 2:38 and the crowd now just needs to act on it: repent and be baptized. Until then, no divinity of Jesus has been preached to the best of my knowledge.

The simple fact is that the concept of son of God was completely different to the concept of Jesus being the literal son / begotten son / part of the trinity.
You can always argue and bring numerous other passages in an attempt to support a position, IMO these will be weak arguments and always lead to contradictions with other passages.
Acts 2 – states ‘God’ – there was no differentiate of the three, father, son, HS.  Peter had no thought of these new concept, which came long time after Jesus.


Acts makes a clear separation from God & Jesus


Acts 2:36 'God has made this Jesus’ (not father or HS, ‘declared’ makes little difference) & would imply God superiority
Acts 2:22 'a man approved of God' – nonsensical for God to approve God


The concept of son and similar generally related to those close to God or chosen of God



Luke 3:38 "...Adam which was the Son of God."


Exodus 4:22 "Israel is my son even my first born."


Jeremiah 31:9 "for I am a father to Israel, and Ephraim is my firstborn."


Genesis 6:2 &4 "That the sons of God saw the daughters of men...and when the sons
of God came in unto the daughters of men..."


angels called sons of God (Job 1:6, 2:1,and 38:7)


Psalms 2:7 "I will declare the decree: the LORD hath said unto me (King David), Thou art my Son; this day have I begotten thee."


Hosea 11:1 Nation of Israel - When Israel was a child, I loved him, and out of Egypt I called my son.


Ex 7:1 And the LORD said unto Moses, See, I have made thee a god to Pharaoh


Psalms 82:6 "I have said, Ye are gods; and all of you are children of the most High.."


Hebrews 1:4 So he became as much superior to the angels as the name
[title - "son"] he has inherited is superior to theirs. 5 For to which of the angels did God ever say, “You are my Son; today I have become your Father”? Or again, “I will be his Father, and he will be my Son”?

[the above and many other passages clearly confirm the usage of son – nothing to do with literal / biological son – otherwise many will have a claim]
There is an attempt to conflate Jesus being the ‘only’ saviour, such as;

1 John 4:14 - And we have seen and testify that the Father has sent his Son to be the Savior of the world.


John 3:16 - For God so loved the world that He gave the only begotten Son, so that everyone believing in Him should not perish, but should have eternal life.

This would IMO contradict other passages

Hosea 13:4 But I am the Lord your God from the land of Egypt; you know no God but me, and besides me there is no savior. (God is the Lord and saviour, at best Trinity position should be God is all 3, therefore all 3 are saviours, not only Jesus)


Isaiah 43:11 - I, I am the Lord, and besides me there is no savior. (same point as above)


Luke 10:27-28
27 The man replied, "The Scriptures say, 'Love the Lord your God with all your heart, soul, strength, and mind.' They also say, 'Love your neighbors as much as you love yourself.'"
28 Jesus said, "You have given the right answer. If you do this, you will have eternal life."


John 17:


Now this is eternal life: that they may know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom you have sent.
I have brought you glory on earth by completing the work you gave me to do.  (work has completed already, no need for sacrifice)


Isaiah 11:
2 - The Spirit of the LORD will rest on Him—the Spirit of wisdom and understanding, the Spirit of counsel and strength, the Spirit of knowledge and fear of the LORD.
3 - And He will delight in the fear of the LORD. He will not judge by what His eyes see, and He will not decide by what His ears hear,
[God cannot fear himself – hierarchy]


Matthew 26:39 Going a little farther, he fell with his face to the ground and prayed, "My Father, if it is possible, may this cup be taken from me. Yet not as I will, but as you will."


Matthew 18:4 - 4. Therefore, whoever humbles himself like this child is the greatest in the kingdom of heaven.


Mark 12:29 - "The most important one," answered Jesus, "is this: 'Hear, O Israel, the Lord our God, the Lord is one.

[differentiation between God and Jesus – love your neighbour is sufficient for eternal life, other routes for salvation]
Similar – is Jesus Judge or not - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/99059/33268
Lord
A few examples of other who are called Lord

Genesis 18:12 Sarah calls Abraham Lord


Genesis 42:30 - The man, who is the lord of the land, spake roughly to us, and took us for spies of the country.


David was called lord by Abigail to avert a disaster (1 Samuel 25:24).
And fell at his feet, and said, Upon me, my lord, upon me let this iniquity be: and let thine handmaid, I pray thee, speak in thine audience, and hear the words of thine handmaid.


Jacob called Esau ‘my lord’ (Genesis 32: 4)
And he commanded them, saying, Thus shall ye speak unto my lord Esau; Thy servant Jacob saith thus, I have sojourned with Laban, and stayed there until now:

So on and on…..


General


One must remember all the knowledge at the time would have come direct from previous scripture / teachings (OT whatever that was at the time) and those who were lucky like the Apostles to have direct teachings from Jesus.
Also, we do not even know who the author of Acts, the use of “we” appears to be sufficient as evidence that it must have been Luke as he was travelling with Paul.
Even accepting that it was Luke, he never met Jesus and appears to be minimal contact with the Apostles to learn about Jesus and was likely to have been influenced by Paul (who also never met Jesus or learnt from the Apostles).
As to Luke being inspired or transcribed from someone inspired – unlikely for the reasons above and Paul’s authority, apostleship, inspiration, vision is purely his record.

Luke clearly not inspired;

"Therefore, since I myself have carefully investigated everything from the beginning, it seemed good also to me to write an orderly account for you, most excellent Theophilus, (Luke 1:3)"

Luke
4:16 He went to Nazareth, where he had been brought up, and on the Sabbath day he went into the synagogue, as was his custom. He stood up to read, 17 and the scroll of the prophet Isaiah was handed to him. Unrolling it, he found the place where it is written:

4:21 - He began by saying to them, “Today this scripture is fulfilled in your hearing.”
[the eye witnesses don’t write about Jesus finding / reading Isaiah scrolls]

how good was his ‘investigation’

Luke 24:46  He told them, "This is what is written: The Christ will suffer and rise from the dead on the third day,
There is nothing like this written in the OT
See: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/79613/33268
>>Conclusion:
There is a clear differentiation from God and Jesus, it does not say ‘Father’, ‘son’ hence no concepts of the 3 in 1 and ‘Son’ is not used in this context either in this passage of in the OT.
Reliability of Luke or Acts is debatable.

-1 Man, this answer is all over the place. I might even agree with some of the points you make, but it is too long and unfocused to endorse including scripture and commentary unnecessary to answer the question.

@Austin Yes and could be much longer - my open para is the answer, bit i felt it would be helpful to cover certain points that are raised to argue something that was never there and came much later that was nothing to do with Jesus.

The fact that Jesus is repeatedly called "Lord" is deeply significant to educated, learned and observant Jews.  This is based on the absolute monotheism of the OT, especially:

Isa 45:18 - For thus says the LORD, who created the heavens—He is God; He formed the earth and fashioned it; He established it; He did not create it to be empty, but formed it to be inhabited: “I am the LORD, and there is no other".
Ex 16:12 - “I have heard the grumbling of the Israelites. Tell them, ‘At twilight you will eat meat, and in the morning you will be filled with bread. Then you will know that I am the LORD your God.’ ”
Isa 41:4 - Who has performed this and carried it out, calling forth the generations from the beginning? I, the LORD—the first and the last—I am.”

See also Eze 20:42 and many, many others.
Little wonder that Peter concluded his sermon with the astonishing statement:

Acts 2:36 - Therefore let all Israel know with certainty that God has
made this Jesus, whom you crucified, both Lord and Christ!”

This is effectively a declaration in one of the most affirmative ways possible to a Jewish audience of the divinity of Jesus.  (Compare also V39.)

Not sure Acts 2:36 is that helpful - 'God has made this Jesus,' so God makes another God!  Acts 2:22 'a man approved of God'  - and you are well aware many have been called Lord

No, God did not make another "god" or even "a god" like the JW's claim. Read what Luke 2:11 states, "for today in the city of David there has been born for you a "SAVIOR, WHO IS CHRIST THE LORD." "Savior" has its background in the OT (yesha) where it is used of God as He acts on behalf of His people Israel (Psalm 25;5, 27:1; Isaiah 45:15; et al.) Moreover, you have at Isaiah 43:11 the following potent words. "I, even I, am the Lord; and there is no SAVIOR besides Me." So, in the Bible we have only one Savior, one Redemer and one Lord who is clearly identified as God. Who might that be?

@anothertheory I read in a commentary that "made Lord" could also mean "declared Lord" in the context of being vindicated through His resurrection. Peter could not be saying that God the Father made/created God the Son.

@Mr.Bond Good points. The only way I see the crowd, mostly coming from foreign nations for Pentecost, understand Jesus' deity is when Peter makes the connection connecting between His resurrection and His lordship.

It seems that Dottard and @Mr.Bond seem to support similar arguments, that Lord and Savior were carrying a divine essence in Jews mind. When Peter ended his sermon, he seemed to have concluded with the most compelling argument: God has made Jesus (Savior) both Lord and Christ (Messiah). Could a Jew have listened to this without concluding that Jesus was indeed God? This answer does not deserve 4 downvote. It is actually the best answer I could get for now. Upvoting it.
