Does Jesus being crucified on a 'tree' have any relation to the tree of the knowledge of good and evil in Eden?

Acts 5:30 - The God of our fathers raised up Jesus, whom you killed,
having hanged Him on a tree.  See also Acts 10:39, 13:29.

There is a lot of symbolism here. The tree of life symbolizes Jesus. Does the other tree symbolize the cross? Was the tree of life nailed to the tree of the knowledge of good and evil leaving only the resurrected tree of life in the end?
I've heard it said that the tree of the knowledge of good and evil = the tree of judgment. God not wanting to bring judgement on man gave a command not to eat of it's fruit. The fruit of judgement / grapes of wrath.
Would the absence of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil equate to Romans 8:1? "There is therefore now no condemnation to those who are in Christ Jesus"

Death entered vis a tree. God used a tree to undo the effects.

Isn't this more of a question of doctrine rather than of textual hermeneutics?

I would say, yes, as a matter of spiritual allusion and in regard to the fact that God nailed the 'handwriting of ordinances which was against us' (that is to say, the knowledge of good and evil as expressed in the Law) . . .  'nailing it to the cross'. But this is interpretive and is going to be difficult to demonstrate hermeneutically. Good question. Up-voted +1.

In John 19:31-32, the order in which the criminals are found is explained by the fact that all three were crucified on a single tree, with only the patibulum used for each.

Actually, this is less clear that it appears.  The operative word in Acts Acts 5:30, 10:39, 13;29 is ξύλον (zulon) which literally means "wood/timber".  It occurs 20 times in the NT and is variously translated:

clubs, Matt 26:47, 55, Mark 14:43, 48, Luke 22:52.
tree, Luke 23:31, Gal 3:13, Rev 2:7, 22:2, 14, 19.
cross, Acts 5:30, 10:39, 13:29, 1 Peter 2:24.
stocks, Acts 16:24.
wood, 1 Cor 3:12, Rev 18:12.

That is, the noun ξύλον (zulon) can serve as the description of anything made of wood.
Now, it is also true that while Jesus was crucified on a wooden cross and that the tree of life is made of wood, so is the tree of the knowledge of good and evil; and so are clubs and stocks.  Theologically, this is as far as we can go.

+1 to cancel pointless downvote. And what do you make of Galatians 3:13, "Christ redeemed us from the curse of the law by becoming a curse for us—for it is written, 'Cursed is everyone who is hanged on a tree'”?

@Dieter - Gal 3:13 is referenced above under the "tree" translation.  It is a valid meaning for the word.

Yes, and Galatians 3:13 refers to Deuteronomy 21:22,23, which reads "And if a man has committed a crime punishable by death and he is put to death, and you hang him on a tree, his body shall not remain all night on the tree, but you shall bury him the same day, for a hanged man is cursed by God. You shall not defile your land that the Lord your God is giving you for an inheritance." Judas also hanged on a tree (by his own hand), and according to an early church writing, he was still alive when he was cut down, but was killed in the fall.

@Dieter Gal 3:13 is implying Jesus is cursed by God, even though he is God and meant to be sinless.  Also, contradictions with many passages you are accountable for your own actions.  Judas 'early church writing' that’s interesting, any source? Or an attempt to explain the contradiction!

@anothertheory - 2 Cor 5:21, God made him who had no sin to be sin for us, so that in him we might become the righteousness of God.  1 Peter 3:18, For Christ also suffered for sins once for all, the righteous for the unrighteous, to bring you to God. He was put to death in the body but made alive in the Spirit.

@anothertheory - note that Christ was sinless but became sin for us to save us.  Jesus took our curse (of sin) by becoming a curse.  This is known as the great divine exchange where Christ was treated as we deserve so that we might be treated as He deserves.

@Dottard  Jesus said he did not come to change 'jot' of what had come before.  when did he take on our sin / curse?

@anothertheory - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/61033/at-what-exact-moment-did-jesus-transition-from-being-rich-to-being-poor-accordin/61039#61039  Jesus became the "Lamb of God" to take away the sin of the world.  Jesus was the substitutionary sacrifice for our sins on the cross.

@Dottard - just to be clear - you imply that Jesus took on our sins at birth, do you have any passages to back that?  So, on earth was Jesus sinful or took on the curse of God but still sinless?

@anothertheory - Heb 7:26 makes clear that Jesus remained sinless AND Jesus took our sin as per Isa 53:4, 5.  The darkness at the cross appears to have occurred during the crucifixion.  Ask another question for more complete information.

Sin and cursed are 2 different things, putting that to the side.  So he took the curse of God but still sinless.   Hebrew 7:26 27 He has no need, like those high priests, to offer sacrifices daily, first for his own sins and then for those of the people, since he did this once for all when he offered up himself. Why did he need to be baptised Mark 1:4 John came baptizing in the wilderness and proclaiming a baptism of repentance for forgiveness of sins.

Jesus was not the only one without sin Gen 17:1 When Abram was ninety-nine years old, the LORD appeared to Abram and said to him, “I am Almighty God; walk before Me and be blameless.  Jesus the ‘Lamb’ goes against the bible and Jesus stated he has not come to change a ‘jot’   https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/75324/33268

@anothertheory - really - what of his sins concerning Pharoah in Gen 12 & 13 and his dalliance with Hagar?  Abraham was NOT sinless and perfectly fits the declaration in Rom 3:10-18.  Abraham was sinner that needed salvation!

@Dottard - and your response to the my comment before!  And what about the contradiction of a sacrificial lamb.  Hagar was his wife

Jesus, the Great Carpenter (see Mark 6:3), transformed the tree of death (the cross, see 2 Corinthians 5:21 and Galatians 3:13) into the tree of life through his sacrificial offering. Through eating the fruit of the tree of life (His Flesh and His Blood), we will inherit eternal life (see John 6:53-58) and reverse the consequences of Adam's consumption of the forbidden fruit through which death entered the world (see Romans 5:12-21.)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Hi, @Community; I have 5 citations in my answer, all of which link to relevant supporting information. I'm not sure what else you could need. My answer is intentionally concise; too many people ramble on excessively on this site and say in 400 words what should be said in 40.
